# How to display a list of recently open files in Windows Forms?

Tags: .net, winforms, c#-4.0

I'm trying to do basically what I asked in the title. I've searched through the interwebs, but [the only answer I found](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/mru.aspx) is from 2003, and I wonder if it doesn't exist a simpler way today.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It would help to provide that answer you found from 2003 so we can compare with it... Also, isn't that just keeping a list saved somewhere with recently open files and just loading that on app startup?

Comment: I thought abou that, but my boss thinks there's an easier way, so I'm trying to figure out if such thing exists.

Answer (score 0):

There are [plenty of implementations on CodeProject](http://www.google.com/search?q=site%3acodeproject.com+mru).

In my applications, I think I originally used [this one](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/mrutoolstripmenu.aspx) and modified it to further fit smoothly into the applications.